# Basic arithmetic operations on int - Java

Tags: java, arithmetic-expressions

I recently noticed an idiosyncrasy of Java regarding basic arithmetic operations in Java. With the following code

```
byte a = 3;
byte b = 4;
byte c = a * b;
```

I get a "type mismatch" compilation error...

Are basic arithmetic operations in Java (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`) only performed on primitive data types of `int` and higher order (`long`, `double`, etc.), whereas arithmetic operations on `byte` and `short` are first cast to `int` and then evaluated?

Comment: Good question. I honestly didn't know the answer, but found this. http://mindprod.com/jgloss/multiplication.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Operations on `byte`, `char` and `short` are widened to `int` unless the compiler can determine the value is in range.

```
final byte a = 3, b = 4;
byte c = a * b; // compiles

final byte a = 3, b = 40;
byte c = a * b; // compiles

final int a = 3, b = 4;
byte c = a * b; // compiles !!
```

but

```
byte a = 3, b = 4;
byte c = a * b; // doesn't compile as the result of this will be `int` at runtime.

final byte a = 30, b = 40;
byte c = a * b; // doesn't compile as the value is too large, will be an `int`
```

BTW This compiles even though it results in an overflow. :]

```
final int a = 300000, b = 400000;
int c = a * b; // compiles but overflows, is not made a `long`
```

Comment: Ouch, I didn't know `final` would make _such_ a difference here. But it looks strange anyway, since even in the second example, `a` and `b` are still declared as bytes...

Comment: *unless the compiler can determine the value is in range* <=> it is a **constant** expression which is in range.

Answer (score 7):

The result of integer operations is either `int` or `long`. This is spelled out in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2):

> **4.2.2. Integer Operations**
>
> The numerical operators, **which result in a value of type `int` or `long`**:
>
> - The unary plus and minus operators + and - (§15.15.3, §15.15.4)
> - The multiplicative operators *, /, and % (§15.17)
> - The additive operators + and - (§15.18)
> - ...

[Also](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> **5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion**
>
> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.
>
> ...
>
> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands of certain operators:
>
> - The multiplicative operators *, / and % (§15.17)
> - The addition and subtraction operators for numeric types + and - (§15.18.2)
> - The numerical comparison operators <, <=, >, and >= (§15.20.1)
> - The numerical equality operators == and != (§15.21.1)
> - The integer bitwise operators &, ^, and | (§15.22.1)
> - In certain cases, the conditional operator ? : (§15.25)