# byte plus byte ?Automatically convert to int for all operands?

Tags: java, types

Here are codes,the last second row couldn't compile out cause of the result is int?So,can I 
solve that every non integer type in java process as integer in arithmetic?
And I am learning English from all guys,thank you.

```
  byte a=0;
    for(int i=0;i<128;i++){
        a=(byte)i;
     }
     byte b=1;
     byte c=0;
     c=b+a;
     System.out.println(b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition operation in java between two `shorts` or `bytes` happens after converting both the operands to `int` and results in an `int`. So you need to cast your result to `byte` as it is a lossy conversion. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125843/basic-arithmetic-operations-on-int-java)

Comment: Suddenly I got  java designed that for byte is too narrow to fill the data,If my turn to do it maybe I would consider it too

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast `a` or the result of the addition of `a` and `b` to a byte, since `a` is an integer and it's value might not fit into a byte.
Example:

```
c = (byte) ((byte) a + b);
```

or

```
c = (byte) (a + b);
```

This way, `b` gets implicitly converted to an integer, the result is then casted to a byte again.

Comment: Actually the first comment of yours can't compile